# QTcpServer: how to return value?

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm writing Client/Server communication system on Qt. I'm using QTcpServer and QtcpSocket. I'm sending some information from client side but how can I return value from server?

> Client Side

```
QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
socket->connectToHost("MyHost", "MyPort");
socket->write("Hello from Client...");
```

> Server Side

```
QtSimpleServer::QtSimpleServer(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    if (listen(QHostAddress::Any, "MyPort"))
    {
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error while listening... " << errorString();
    }
}

void QtSimpleServer::incomingConnection(int handle)
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);

    connect (socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
}

void QtSimpleServer::onReadyRead()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    qDebug() << socket->readAll();

    socket->disconnectFromHost();
    socket->close();
    socket->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: You may use `socket->write` method. Btw, you should note, that packet may be fragmented, and it's not guranteed that you will reveice all data with one all of `readAll()`.

Comment: how can I return value from server? what value? you may need to save client pointer for further

Comment: @saeed For example: I want to send to client "Hello from server". How can I do it?

Comment: @J.Doe if you think my post is correct you can accept.

Comment: @saeed I didn't check because I found another way to do it but +1 anyway..

Answer (score 3):

Save each client pointer for further respond.

```
QVector<QTcpSocket*> clients;
void QtSimpleServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    connect (socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    clients << socket;
}

void QtSimpleServer::sendHelloToAllClient()
{
    foreach ( QTcpSocket * client, clients) {
        client->write(QString("Hello Client").toLatin1());
        client->flush();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

This is only a simple solution to show save a reference for objects which is created inside a scope and should be referenced later.

if you want to practice more complex server/client application, It's better to have look on [Threaded Fortune Server Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html)  and [Fortune Client Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html)